# How to have vertical scrolling in Webviews that are inside a Scrollview?

Tags: android, webview, scrollview, touch-event

I have a Webview that is embedded inside a scrollview. The Webview itself has areas that are vertical scrollable.

Now if I try to scroll inside the webview, the scrollview intercepts the touchevent and scrolls the whole webview instead that only the small scrollable div is moved.

How can I make the scrollview work only if the webview does not want to scroll?

Comment: hello @Janusz I m facing same problem. did you find solution for that? if yes please post as your answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Our solution uses a Javascript callback through the [Javascript Interface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29). Every time a part of the UI that is scrollable inside the WebView is touched a listener is called through java script and this listener calls [requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewParent.html#requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent%28boolean%29) on the WebViews parent.

This is not optimal but the nicest solution found at the moment. If the user scrolls very fast the layer in the WebView won't scroll but at a normal scroll rate it works fine.

Comment: can you please share some code for this that you used.

Answer (score 0):

@Janusz, I have had the same problem. My solution is based on the extended scroll view behaviour in couple with the correct layout. I have wrote the answer to the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12963499/1152250).
Let me know in case you have implementation problems or questions and, please inform whether it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have a webview within a scrollview container, and the scrollview and webview are full screen.  I was able to fix this by overriding the onTouch event in my webView touchListener.

```
   scrollView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollview); 

   webView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {           
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            scrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            return false;
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use TouchyWebView.java

```
public class TouchyWebView extends WebView {

    public TouchyWebView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TouchyWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public TouchyWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
        requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }          
}
```

In layout file:

```
<yourclasapath.TouchyWebView 
                android:id="@+id/description_web"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 />
```