# react-native - How do I scroll a Webview inside scrollview for android?

Tags: webview, react-native, react-native-scrollview

I want to use WebView inside ScrollView for my react native app. But if I do so, I am not able to scroll my webview, unless I disable the scroll on scrollview. However, I need the scroll in both scrollview as well as webview.
Any suggestions or solutions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: facing same issues, I am able to scroll horizontally but vertical scroll is causing the issue....any fixes so far

Comment: This might help you [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257990/android-webview-inside-scrollview-scrolls-only-scrollview)

Answer (score 5):

I am also searching for this issue on the internet for the last 2-3 days and I have got an awesome solution for this ...

```
npm install --save react-native-webview-autoheight
```

After installing this with no issues

```
import MyWebView from "react-native-webview-autoheight";

<ScrollView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "white" }}>
  <View
    style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "column", backgroundColor: "white" }}
    pointerEvents={"none"}
  >
    <Text>Hi I am at top</Text>
    <MyWebView
      //sets the activity indicator before loading content
      startInLoadingState={true}
      source={{
        uri:
          "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43781301/react-native-how-do-i-scroll-a-webview-inside-scrollview-for-android"
      }}
    />
    <Text>Hi I am at bottom</Text>
  </View>
</ScrollView>
```

it works perfectly for me..

Comment: Hi @Tijo Thomas thanks much.                                                                                <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', backgroundColor: 'white' }} pointerEvents={'none'}>                                                                                                         This style worked for me

Comment: @Pruthvi I was looking for something like `pointerEvents={'none'}` Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

try to set nestedScrollEnabled={true} for Webview

Answer (score 1):

I fix bug scroll `Webview` inside `ScrollView`. I override func `onTouchEvent` if not only `Webview` catch event `onTouch` call `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);`.

You can try my repo 
https://github.com/thepday12/react-native-webview

- package.json

  "react-native-webview": "https://github.com/thepday12/react-native-webview",
- Using

  import WebView from 'react-native-webview';
- Source from https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/?

Answer (score 0):

use TouchyWebView.java

```
public class TouchyWebView extends WebView {
public TouchyWebView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public TouchyWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public TouchyWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

and in layout

```
<yourpachagename.TouchyWebView
                android:id="@+id/webView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
heightValue = 1000 // putting 100 will let the Webview scroll normally.
```

```
<View> <Text> Viewtiful </Text> </View>  

<WebView
    source={{uri: 'www.reddit.com'}}
    style={{height:heightValue}}
/>
```

Found this [here.](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10723#issue-187131368)

Answer (score 0):

this saved me: https://github.com/archriss/react-native-render-html/

```
      [...] 
      import { ScrollView, Dimensions, Button } from 'react-native';

      import HTML from 'react-native-render-html';
      [...] 

      <ScrollView>
        <Text>{strings.title}</Text>
        <HTML
          html={htmlText}
          imagesMaxWidth={Dimensions.get('window').width}
          baseFontStyle={styles.html}
        />
        <Button
          style={styles.button}
          onButtonPressed={this.handleAcceptPress}
          text={strings.accept}
        />
      </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wanna use any 3rd party library here is the solution for you.
modify your WebView code with this.

```js
<WebView
  originWhitelist={['*']}
  scrollEnabled={false}
  onMessage={onMessage}
  onNavigationStateChange={navigationChanged}
  injectedJavaScript="window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(Math.max(document.body.offsetHeight, document.body.scrollHeight));"
  source={{html: htmlCode}}
/>
```

After adding this code you need to create a method for onMessage by which you'll get the height of your WebView Content.

```js
const[webViewHeight, setWebViewHeight] = useState(0);
const onMessage = event => {
    setWebViewHeight(Number(event.nativeEvent.data));
};
```

Now, you got the height of your webview and you can simply pass that height to your webview style prop. ie.,

> style={{height: webViewHeight}}

That's all. you got the webview working completely with the scrollview. if you got any query feel free to ask me.

Answer (score -1):

Try next code

```html
<ScrollView>
  <Text>Text before ScrollView</Text>
  <WebView
    source={{
      uri:
        "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43781301/react-native-how-do-i-scroll-a-webview-inside-scrollview-for-android"
    }}
    style={{
      marginTop: 20,
      height: 100
    }}
  />
  <Text>Text after ScrollView</Text>
  <WebView
    source={{
      uri:
        "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43781301/react-native-how-do-i-scroll-a-webview-inside-scrollview-for-android"
    }}
    style={{
      marginTop: 20,
      height: 100
    }}
  />
</ScrollView>
```

[image]

Comment: if we don't know the height of the webview it don't work.

Comment: this example is not complete, it will also not work as soon as you add more content to it

Answer (score -1):

This fixed all of my issues

```
npm install react-native-autoheight-webview react-native-webview
```

```js
import AutoHeightWebView from 'react-native-autoheight-webview'
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native'


<AutoHeightWebView
    style={{ width: Dimensions.get('window').width - 15, marginTop: 35 }}
    customScript={`document.body.style.background = 'lightyellow';`}
    customStyle={`
      * {
        font-family: 'Times New Roman';
      }
      p {
        font-size: 16px;
      }
    `}
    onSizeUpdated={size => console.log(size.height)}
    files={[{
        href: 'cssfileaddress',
        type: 'text/css',
        rel: 'stylesheet'
    }]}
    source={{ html: `<p style="font-weight: 400;font-style: normal;font-size: 21px;line-height: 1.58;letter-spacing: -.003em;">Tags are great for describing the essence of your story in a single word or phrase, but stories are rarely about a single thing. <span style="background-color: transparent !important;background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(146, 249, 190, 1), rgba(146, 249, 190, 1));">If I pen a story about moving across the country to start a new job in a car with my husband, two cats, a dog, and a tarantula, I wouldn’t only tag the piece with “moving”. I’d also use the tags “pets”, “marriage”, “career change”, and “travel tips”.</span></p>` }}
    scalesPageToFit={true}
    viewportContent={'width=device-width, user-scalable=no'}
    /*
    other react-native-webview props
    */
  />
```

Comment: Which exact line solves the scrolling issue?

Comment: scalesPageToFit try changing that. rest is automatic .