# I want to scroll the scrollview not the webview

Tags: java, android

[Android WebView inside ScrollView scrolls only scrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257990/android-webview-inside-scrollview-scrolls-only-scrollview)

I've tried many solutions above similar question.
But these are all about the scrolls inside the webview.
So I've succeed about about the inside scrolls.

But I want to try Scrolls that is outside of the webview. Which is Main scrollView.
This Scrollview must scrolls the list of webview but Doesn't work at all

```
view.setVerticallScrollBarEnabled(true);
view.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
view.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);
```

Is there anyone who can give me sites or Hints for that?

I know it is difficult and not good to do that. 
But I need this solution.

**Updated!**
It is not for webview I'll show my activity what I'm doing right now.
The Scrollview is not a activity's layout. It is just scrollview that I applied to activity main view.

[image]

Comment: Webview has its own scroll. Why do you want a scrollview on top of it

Comment: @ROHITLIEN , Because It is group of webviews... I want the item of webview to be listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace `ScrollView` with `NestedScrollView`

and Add this line in onCreate `view.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);`

Hope this help.

Comment: I thought this function is for the webview's scroll event.
Would this work with for scrollview?

Answer (score 1):

make NestedScrollView fillViewport = "false" and WebView layout_height = "wrap_content"

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="false"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/read_full_content_wv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```