# Best way to create a header and footer for webview in Android

Tags: android, android-webview, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-scrollview

I want to create news like activity that has title and date and some share and favorite buttons in the beginning at the top, the article text (and maybe some images and headers titles) is in html that I get from server, and at the end a list of related news!

I have to use WebView for the article html, but since I need the header and the main webview to scroll together, I may have to use them in the in wraping ScrollView, which, apparently is not the best option!

I have red these:
[webview in scrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9718245/webview-in-scrollview) and
[Disable scrolling in webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527899/disable-scrolling-in-webview/5274400#5274400)

but I want to know what is the best way to implement this as of 2015! that can work with android 4.01+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as it turns out, best way to do yet is to just put them in a scrollView !

It worked on my Samsung android 4.4, but I don't know about the rest !

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/news_activity_title_lay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       //Some Widgets Here for header

    </RelativeLayout>

    <WebView
        android:layout_below="@+id/news_activity_title_lay"
        android:id="@+id/news_activity_web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white">

    </WebView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/news_activity_related_base_lay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/news_activity_web_view">

      //Some Widgets Here foe footer

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

funny thing, though is Android Studio is saying I should not do this ! :/

Comment: Works like a charm (Android 6).