# Android ScrollView automatically scrolls to the bottom of the view

Tags: android

I have created one activity which is containing one map, image and another text view, and I have added "scrollview" tag for it. But after the activity starts it scrolls to the end of the page automatically. Please tell me why this happens and how to stop it from moving to end so I can scroll it by myself.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.radikallab.earch.DetailsActivity"
android:background="@drawable/background10">


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textStyle="italic"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/background4"
        android:id="@+id/iv"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textStyle="italic"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/addr"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textStyle="italic"/>

    <WebView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 71):

I also face the same scenario once but adding the descendantFocusability attribute to the ScrollView's containing LinearLayout, solve my issue.

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

you can use this as :

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >
```

Comment: Is there any other way to block any sort of auto-scrolling that does not disable focus? I have TextViews with selection capability inside of the LinearLayout. Using this method disables text selection.

Answer (score 12):

Set `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` in your linear layout:

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me is a combination of the answers from Punit Sharma and FAЯAƸ.

My issue was a scrollable view (RecyclerView) inside another scrollable view (NestedScrollView) -- same as your WebView inside a ScrollView.

Wrapping my inner scrollable view inside a `FragmentLayout` with attribute `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` solved my auto-to-bottom-scrolling issue.

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        ....

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
            ...>
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/image_gridview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
       </FrameLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you do want to set this manually using Java;
Try this- it really works:
Use FOCUS_UP to scroll to the top and FOCUS_DOWN to scroll it to the Bottom.

```
scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);
                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually i found a simple answer for this just add "setfocusable(false)" in the associated java file.....in this case the "webview" coz its scroll there first....so add "webview.setfocusable(false)" in the associated webview java class.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, we will face the scrolling problem if child inside `ScrollView` supports scrolling too like `ListView` and in your case `WebView`.

I found a similar question with some workaround. It supports vertical scrolling but horizontal scrolling is not supported  if `HTML` page exceeds the `WebView`  width.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9718245/webview-in-scrollview) for reference.